# How to recover private key if I have the 12-word and an address?

Tags: recover-private-key

5 years ago I created a Copay app, and I can not import it or recover it. I have the 12 word all the address. Leftover money stays there. But I can not import anymore with Copay. Something wrong, I do not know what.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your mnemonic (12 word) confirms to **BIP32/BIP44**, you can try this `pip3 install btc-address-dump`

Here is an example:

```
$ btc_address_dump "olympic wine chicken argue unaware bundle tunnel grid spider slot spell need"
mnemonic = olympic wine chicken argue unaware bundle tunnel grid spider slot spell need
private key (hex) = c7ac679b56f50bfd54dd924fe45a8dca7a1c2dced254b03dac22afc03adb9127
private key (WIF) = 5KLDyKtrScLYsKMJzVCt8Mf6Nn9DEV7V3fg8njfSZnqe7ZEMqzK
private key (WIF compressed) = L3urFcPsE2yHf5zeQjVSfUB8j8FEzX5cnmhjNsJfqjKgowPP4tmg
public key (uncompressed) = 044cd0aaeca3b636078583408e75edd77307b5190ca7a48bb9fbc1f2576c17dff1087190d91e26af594e3f8ecd3f4d3596c03c45d3b235da916903c930c6593cc4
public key (compressed) = 024cd0aaeca3b636078583408e75edd77307b5190ca7a48bb9fbc1f2576c17dff1
legacy address (p2pkh uncompressed) = 1Q5RqZctfcNkTPad2tuJSREByd2gB8xs63
legacy address (p2pkh compressed) = 12W36tm2jnreFiYdrzfE6cvRaKRbicEpnA
p2sh-segwit address (p2sh p2wpkh) = 3AzXxVUqdzvzEqVmdtmeVqRwc98uqwyh76
bech32 address (p2wpkh) = bc1qzp6lz6zy9p7k68r0a7lzfpkdxvj3yapynzuatt
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 12 words (the seed) on another wallet, electrum (https://electrum.org) for example.